# Cross browser bug (I tried CSS reset)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have serious issues cross browser and I have no idea why. I am using a theme, which normally has no such issues and I have tried using a CSS reset. The issue can be seen on this image https://imgur.com/a/B8pc5qP. If I have two boxes they look completely different in Safari and Chrome, which makes it impossible to style it, as there is always much more whitespace under on the Chrome version.

The issue has to do with headings. The padding below / space below is much less in Safari for all headings.

Comment: The linked image does not appear to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears you are using good old `clearfix`. `clearfix` expects there to be `float`ed children. Adding `float:left;` to the last element is what `clearfix` expects. I did the following and those boxes appear similar in Chrome & Safari.

```
<div class="column_attr clearfix" style="background-color:#ffffff;box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);">
    <h3>Bonzo</h3>
    <h3></h3>
    <h6 style="float: left;">A better food experience.</h6>
</div>
```

1. I'd suggest doing this via CSS, I just did this via HTML for the example.

```
.clearfix h6 {
    float: left;
}
```